# How to create a factory, which creates classes according to interface type in Java?

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I'm working on migrating a C# project to java.

In the C# project I have a factory class holding a dictionary between Type, and a delegate which creates appropriate type.

I expose a generic method:

```
T Create<T>()
```

So the user can write:

```
var someObject = factory.Create<ISomeInterface>();
```

The Create method code is something like:

```
return (T)dictionary[typeof(T)]();
```

The question is, How can I do something similar in Java (version 7)?

Thanks a lot for anyone who would help!

Comment: Can the types be generic?

Comment: No, the only types allowed are interfaces inheriting from some base interface. (there is a constraint - where T : IBase)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In java, generic type parameters information is not available during runtime. So it's impossible in the Create() method to get a corresponding Class object from the type parameter T. If you want to have such a factory, you can have a type provider interface

```
public interface IProvider<T extends IBase> {
  T getInstance();
}
```

then use a `HashMap<Class<? extends IBase>, IFactory<? extends IBase>>` to maintain the factory list. So you can invoke the following method to get a new instance:

```
private HashMap<Class<? extends IBase>, IFactory<? extends IBase>> map;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T> T create(Class<T> type) {
    return (T) map.get(type).getInstance();
}
```

To use the `create(Class<?>)` method, for example, you call it as the following:

```
ISomeInterface someObject = create(ISomeInterface.class);
```

Note that it's your responsibility to make sure the key type and factory's return type in `map` match, or a ClassCastException will be thrown.

If you don't need the types being created extending `IBase`, just omit all the `extends IBase` in the code snippets.

Here's a full example:

```
package com.example.playground;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class TypeFactory {

    public interface IBase { }

    public interface IProvider <T extends IBase> {
        T getInstance();
    }

    private HashMap<Class<? extends IBase>, IProvider<? extends IBase>> registry =
            new HashMap<>();

    public <T extends IBase> void addProvider(Class<T> type, IProvider<T> provider) {
        registry.put(type, provider);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T extends IBase> T create(Class<T> type) {
        return (T) registry.get(type).getInstance();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TypeFactory factory = new TypeFactory();

        factory.addProvider(ISomeInterface.class, new IProvider<ISomeInterface>() {
            @Override
            public ISomeInterface getInstance() {
                return new ISomeInterface() {
                    @Override
                    public String toString() {
                        return "I'm a class that implements ISomeInterface";
                    }
                };
            }
        });

        ISomeInterface obj = factory.create(ISomeInterface.class);
        System.out.println(obj);
    }

}

interface ISomeInterface extends TypeFactory.IBase { }
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as the types you want to store in the `IDictionary` (or `Map` in Java) do not have type parameters, you're ok, and you can easily do something similar to a C# version. I decided to make all members of `Factory` static, but you can do the same thing with an instance method `create` instead.

```
public final class Factory {

    private Factory() {}

    private static interface InnerFactory<T> {
        T produce();
    }

    private static final class StringFactory implements InnerFactory<String> {
        @Override
        public String produce() {
            return "Random String " + Integer.toString(new Random().nextInt());   
        }
    }

    private static final class IntegerFactory implements InnerFactory<Integer> {
        @Override
        public Integer produce() {
            return new Random().nextInt();
        }
    }

    private static final Map<Class<?>, InnerFactory<?>> map = new HashMap<Class<?>, InnerFactory<?>>();

    private static <T> void put(Class<T> clazz, InnerFactory<T> innerFactory) {
        map.put(clazz, innerFactory);
    }

    static {
        put(String.class, new StringFactory());
        put(Integer.class, new IntegerFactory());
    }

    public static <T> T create(Class<T> clazz) {
        return clazz.cast(map.get(clazz).produce());
    }
}
```

You can now call `Factory.create(String.class)` from elsewhere. This breaks down in Java if you try and do the same thing if one of the types `T` has type parameters. Then it becomes a lot more complicated because, due to type erasure, expressions like `List<String>.class` are not legal code.

Comment: I think the C# code in the OP means that they want to create a new object of the given type when the function is called, not an existing object.